# Join on two table with same primary key but different data

Tags: android, sqlite, join

I am trying to join two tables that are identical in structure. I want my join to choose the data from second table if row for same primary key exist in both. For instance, if I have the following tables with data -

[image]
[image]

I want join to give me something like this -

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT table1._id, COALESCE(table2.data, table1.data) 
    FROM table1 
    LEFT JOIN table2 USING _id;
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. I had to make only one minor change. Here is the final query - SELECT
 tableA."_id",
 COALESCE(tableB.data, tableA.data) as data
FROM
 tableA
LEFT JOIN tableB USING (_id);